# UITableView Cell at Index 0 Size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

What is the best way to customize the first cell in a table to display like the Netflix application (i.e. bigger/different)? For ease of future use, I have been asked to use IB as much as possible to make it easier for future editing.

Here is a photo of the Netflix table. http://cl.ly/3j1d473d1j160502160t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the table header view. Drag a view to the top of the table view and it will become the "table header view".

If you have other such "cells" which are essentially constant (and might be switched on/off) you can consider putting `UITableViewCell` objects in your xib, and returning them from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. Also implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Both can have the same general outline, like:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)ip
{
    if ( ip.section==0 ) return headerCell;
    // ...handle regular cells
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)ip
{
    if ( ip.section==0 ) return headerCell.frame.size.height;
    // ...handle regular cells
    return 44;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either make it something that isn't a cell (like the table's header view), or implement [`-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) to return a different height. You can use IB to install a table header, but more complex ways of attacking this problem will require working in code.

Comment: I stand corrected! It appears to be drag & drop only (tableHeaderView isn't an outlet), but it's definitely possible. Thanks, mvds!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that you can use.It is table's header view...

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

```
 if(section==0){ UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableview.frame.size.width, 44)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; UILabel
*label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)]; 
[label setText:@"Hello!!"];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
[view addSubview:label]; return view; 
 }return nil;
```

}
Here You can set the height for the tableViewHeaderSection.

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

  return 100;
  }